# opencv RNG alternative for Java

Tags: java, opencv, random

I use opencv-3.2.0, I found RNG can use with C++, but not exist in Java:

C++

```
RNG rng( 0xFFFFFFFF );
rng.uniform( -3, 10 );
rng.uniform(0, 200);
```

Java

```
There is no RNG
```

Please tell me how to use RNG uniform in Java.

Comment: Can't you use Java builtin functions to generate random numbers instead of OpenCV?

Comment: I can, but i want to known, is there have an alternative RNG in java.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small search on `google`, I found this [link](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core.RNG.html), in the explanation of `uniform`, it says:

> returns uniformly distributed integer random number from [a,b) range. The methods transform the state using the MWC algorithm and return the next uniformly-distributed random number of the specified type, deduced from the input parameter type, from the range [a, b) .

And the examples:

```
RNG rng;

// always produces 0
double a = rng.uniform(0, 1);

// produces double from [0, 1)
double a1 = rng.uniform((double)0, (double)1);

// produces float from [0, 1)
double b = rng.uniform(0.f, 1.f);

// produces double from [0, 1)
double c = rng.uniform(0., 1.);

// may cause compiler error because of ambiguity:
//  RNG::uniform(0, (int)0.999999)? or RNG::uniform((double)0, 0.99999)?
double d = rng.uniform(0, 0.999999);
```

So, it seems java also have `RNG`.

Comment: Thank you so much.It means that opencv for java, have no offical RNG, we should get it other way?